# Tracking the movement of the watch hand

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I love watches, and I had an idea for a weird kind of watch movement (all of the stuff that moves the hands). It is made up of a a central wheel, with one of the hands connected to it (in this case, it will be the hour hand). This hand goes through a pivot, and then displays the time. I attached a video of a 3d mock up [here](https://youtu.be/5-OmzIeNhwg), because it is kinda hard to explain. My question is, is there any functions that would be able to graph the movement of the end of the hand? I don't want to make the real prototype just yet.

Comment: That watch looks awesome but do you think it will be physically implementable?

Comment: I think it would be. The only thing I am kinda afraid of would be friction at the pivot, and telling the hour from 5-7 might be tough, but who knows. I love weird watches, and its certainly weird.

Comment: Which end of the hand are you talking about? The one that actually shows the hour, or the other end?

Comment: The side of the hand that isn’t attached to the whee

Comment: I am also worried about the friction as it may slow down the transition. Use plenty of graphite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will take the origin to be the place the hand slides through, $y$ vertical positive up, $x$ horizontal positive right.  Let the hand have length $L$ and the circle radius $R$.  It appears $L$ is a little greater than $2R$, so it sticks out of the pivot even when the left end is at the farthest left point.

The position of the left end is $(R\cos ft-R,R\sin ft)$ where $f=\frac {2 \pi}{ 12 hours}$
The distance from the left end to the pivot is $\sqrt{(R\cos ft-R)^2+(R\sin ft)^2}=\sqrt{2R^2-2R\cos ft}$
The slope of the hand is $\frac {R \sin ft}{R\cos ft-R}=m$
The length of the hand to the right of the pivot is $L-\sqrt{2R^2-2R\cos ft}$
The position of the right end of the hand is $\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{1+m^2}}(L-\sqrt{2R^2-2R\cos ft}),\frac m{\sqrt{1+m^2}}(L-\sqrt{2R^2-2R\cos ft})\right)$

Comment: Yep. graphed it out, and that's the path. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Denote with $l$ the length of the hand and with $R$ the radius of the circle.

Parametric coordinates of point $M$ (as a function of $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$) are:

$$x_M=(l-2R\cos\frac\alpha2)\cos\frac\alpha2=l\cos\frac\alpha2-R(1+\cos\alpha)$$

$$y_M=-(l-2R\cos\frac\alpha2)\sin\frac\alpha2=-l\sin\frac\alpha2+R\sin\alpha$$

As an exercise you can eliminate angle $\alpha$ and obtain an implicit relation between coordinates of point $M$, but there is not much that you can do with it. It is better to work with parametric equations. Select $l,R$ and calculate coordinates for a range of $\alpha$ angles.